# element type is invalid: expected a string but got: undefined Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to rerun this Soundcloud player app, but I am having some issues along the way. I'm new to the react environment, so debugging some of the basic errors is kinda hard for me.

A quick look from a regular coder would solve them quickly.

[Youtube vid] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrsBXKr6gdg

[Snack link] https://snack.expo.io/@wcandillon/soundcloud-player

Starting from scratch I got the above error. Any leads would be appreciated, Thanks!!

You can find my short code snippet here:
https://snack.expo.io/@harpreetsingh31/soundcloud-player

Comment: Check your imports, make sure they aren't undefined.

Comment: I think i was able to fix that error by opening up the brackets.but now i got this cannot read property 'get' undefined error.